# how to create a multi dimensional array in javascript inside a jquery each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, each

I have this example:

```
var name;
var id;
var array = []; 

$.each(data, function(index, element) {
name = element.name;
id = element.id;
array[id] = name;
<a href="#" onClick="myFunction(array)">send</a>
console.log(array);
});
```

In this case `.each` will iterate 5 times and `id` will become `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and `name` will change to five names

i would like to create a multidimensional array or an object that will look like this:

```
[1:name1] for the first iteration
[2:name2] for the second on
...
```

the pass each pair of values to the `myFunction` function
and inside that function to have access to the array values:

function myFunction(array){
    // alert the key and value
}

Any ideas how can I accomplish this scenario?

Comment: The first code sample has a bunch of HTML suddenly in the middle of it and won't parse. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Patriotccow - Considering the first item of your "inner-array" acts as an identifier, you might want to look into `associative arrays` instead of multi-dimensional. Alternatively, since you're using numbers starting with 1, use a standard single-dimensional array and just ignore the zero-indexed item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but if you want each entry in `array` to be an array containing the values of the id and name, you can change this line:

```
array[id] = name;
```

to

```
array[id] = new Array(id, name);
```

But I probably wouldn't use an array for that, I'd probably just use an object:

```
array[id] = {id: id, name: name};
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
x = array[id].name;
```

In fact, does `array` really need to be an array at all? If not, just make it an object:

```
data = {};
```

Make `id` the key and `name` the value:

```
data[id] = name;
```

And this is how you loop it:

```
function myFunction(data) {
    var id, name;

    for (id in data) {
        name = data[id];
        alert("id is " + id + ", name is " + name);
    }
}
```

With a plain object like that, there's no need, but if the object you're looping may have a prototype behind it, you'd want to only look at the object's *own* properties:

```
function myFunction(data) {
    var id, name;

    for (id in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            name = data[id];
            alert("id is " + id + ", name is " + name);
        }
    }
}
```